# Error while parsing xml in Python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse this: http://www.codespot.blogspot.in/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500

Problem being:

1. I've to store the xml in a file for ElementTree to parse it. How to avoid it and just parse the string response from the GET request?
2. Though I'm doing this, to get all the titles, it still doesn't work:

   ```
   f = open('output.xml','wb+')
       f.write(r.content)
       f.close()
       tree = ""
       with open('output.xml', 'rt') as f:
           tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
           print tree
           root = tree.getroot()
           for elem in tree.iter():
               print elem.tag, elem.attrib
           for atype in tree.findall('title'):
               print atype.contents
   ```

Comment: Explain  "doesn't work".

Comment: Shows up empty. I want the titles and content of each post.

Comment: To parse a string and not a file, you use ElementTree.fromstring(string), but you don't need to do that. namit found the correct namespace use before me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib2
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
conn = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.codespot.blogspot.in/atom.xml?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500")
myins=ET.parse(conn)
for elem in myins.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title'):
    print elem.text
```

or to find the both title and content::

```
for elem in myins.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
    print elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title').text ## this will be the title
    print elem.find('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content').text ## this will be the content
```